# Heroku does not see my fragments

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, heroku, thymeleaf

I successfully deployed my Spring app on Heroku, but when I try to test my app in action I receive 
`Error resolving template "/fragments/head.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (home:4)` Error.
It's odd, because locally my app works well without any problem.

Home.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <div th:replace="/fragments/head.html"></div>
  <title>Personal blog - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div th:replace="/fragments/header" th:class="row"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="container border w-100 post" th:each="post : ${posts}">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-5">
          <a th:href="@{/post/} + ${post.id}" th:text="${post.title}"></a>
        </h1>
        <small class="text-muted" th:text="${post.creationDate}"></small>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <p class="lead text-justify" th:text="${post.contents}"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="pagination justify-content-center" th:if="${lastPageIndex} gt 1">
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link"
             th:if="${currentPage gt 1}"
             th:href="@{/home/} + ${currentPage-1}">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" th:if="${currentPage-3} ge 1"
             th:href="@{/home/} + ${currentPage-3}"
             th:text="${currentPage-3}"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link"
             th:if="${currentPage-2} ge 1"
             th:href="@{/home/} + ${currentPage-2}"
             th:text="${currentPage-2}"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link"
             th:if="${currentPage-1} ge 1"
             th:href="@{/home/} + ${currentPage-1}"
             th:text="${currentPage-1}"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" th:text="${currentPage}"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link"
             th:if="${currentPage+1} le ${lastPageIndex}"
             th:href="@{/home/} + ${currentPage+1}"
             th:text="${currentPage+1}"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link"
             th:if="${currentPage+2} le ${lastPageIndex}"
             th:href="@{/home/} + ${currentPage+2}"
             th:text="${currentPage+2}"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link"
             th:if="${currentPage+3} le ${lastPageIndex}"
             th:href="@{/home/} + ${currentPage+3}"
             th:text="${currentPage+3}"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link"
             th:if="${currentPage} lt ${lastPageIndex}"
             th:href="@{/home/} + ${currentPage+1}">Next</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div th:replace="/fragments/footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Head.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <div th:fragment="head">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb"/>
  </div>
</head>
</html>
```

As you can see, my Head.html contains links to CSS files, one with bootstrap, second with my own fixes. Locally, everything works fine. Every view is loaded perfectly I got only little half-second lag between loading page and applying css to it, but I think on heroku it will be fine.

My aspp is available under this link: https://spring-personal-blog.herokuapp.com

Also entire code of my app is available in [repository](https://github.com/Gromo13/personalBlog/tree/heroku) on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have invalid `th:replace` syntax. Should use

   ```
   th:replace="fragments/head :: head" 
   // or 
   th:replace="fragments/head"  // instead of th:replace="/fragments/head" 

   th:replace="directory/filename :: fragmentName"
   ```

   And similar changes for every other fragment in your template
2. `<div>` inside you `<head>`, you should probably use `th:remove="tag"`.

   ```
   //home.html
   <div th:replace="fragments/head :: head" th:remove="tag"></div> 

   //fragments/head.html
   <head th:fragment="head">...</head>
   ```

---

PS. I played with your github project and its kinda strange that your notation actually works on localhost but breaks on heroku. And the above fixes solved it for me on heroku [DEMO](https://afternoon-garden-26567.herokuapp.com/home/1). Btw I also had to put `passwordEncoder` bean in different config file, because it could not start on heroku otherwise

Comment: I found that when I redeploy my app for the second time to the same heroku repository, it throws error because of circualr reference to PasswordEncoder. I do not know why. Locally everything works fine.

Comment: I read once more your post and moved PasswordEncoder configuration to separate file. Everything works fine. There was only little problem with `/` before every view-name string in controllers but I fixed it in a minute.
Once more thank you very much for help.